# Static serving Socket.IO on Azure NodeJS WebApp

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

I am having a problem with serving socket.io.js on Azure NodeJs WebApp.

The file is found correctly and served, but some characters are attached to the response at the beginning and at the end like this (making it unusable as script):

[image]

The static serving works well on local machines (configured like [this](https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express)), and i also can get Socket.IO from CDN correctly (but that wouldn't be an ideal solution in a long run).

Environment:

- NodeJs v7.4.0 - Win - x86
- Express 4.15.4
- Socket.IO 2.2.0

Is there any idea what causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, there are two possible reason will cause the issue.

1. To deploy a Node app on Azure WebApps, the [`iisnode`](https://github.com/Azure/iisnode) used is the only difference with local deployment. So I suggest you can try to only upload your `socket.io.js` file in the path `wwwroot` to check it whether fine without `iisnode` via directly access `https://<your-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/socket.io.js` with browser or `curl`. Then, you can confirm the issue which was caused by `iisnode` or others. If `iisnode`, you can post an issue on https://github.com/Azure/iisnode/issues to ask for help.
2. The `f3d5` & `0` symbols seems to be [`BOM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) & [`EOF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) which be made in the code editor or IDE you used and rendered by `express.js`/middlewares. If yes, you can change your editor settings or use some tools like `Notepad++`/[`sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file) to remove it.

Comment: Ye, I ended up doing your 1.suggestion, and granted direct access to socket.io.js, and it works correctly. It works for now, but it's kind of a subpar solution, since I have to pay attention to that too, when I change Socket.IO version. I'll investigate on the iisnode some more.
On your 2. suggestion, maybe it is right, but I really don't  want to change the file, which is downloaded via npm.
Anyway, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @ZsoltMedgyesi My suggestions just help you to judge which the possible reason is. If iisnode cause the issue really, you can reproduce it via deploy your app on IIS & iisnode of your local machine.